# Convert BeginInvoke Code From Winforms To Wpf

Tags: wpf, begininvoke

I have found out that ISynchronizeInvoke cannot be used in WPF after having tried to convert the following code unsuccessfully. Can anybody help?

```
private static void EVENT_R(Delegate @event, object[] data)
{
    if (@event != null)
    {
        foreach (var A_C in @event.GetInvocationList())
        {
            var NewTp = (ISynchronizeInvoke)A_C.Target;
            if (NewTp != null && NewTp.InvokeRequired)
            {
                NewTp.BeginInvoke(A_C, data);
            }
            else
            {
                A_C.DynamicInvoke(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758233/winforms-to-wpf-conversion-begininvoke-to-what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If NewTp is a `UIElement`, then you need to cast to `UIElement` and call `UIElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`:

```
var NewTp = (UIElement)A_C.Target;
if (NewTp != null)
{
    NewTp.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(A_C, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your first answer I had already looked at but it didn't quite match the code I am using. This answer is perfect ... all with the minimum amount of code!